# Estimate Weibull parameters from cumulative density

Tags: r, probability-density, weibull

I have cumulative probabilities from a Weibull cumulative density distribution and would like to find the underlying function parameters.

The data:

```
At <- data.frame(cumu = c(0.004722245,0.004740720,0.008768300,0.010900330,0.194195851,0.215752640,0.226863587,0.237534826,0.240753194,0.324707908,0.354541558,0.421462196,0.421879734,0.423690298,0.454939143,0.597567194,0.647963670,0.688549850,0.729575737,0.742892615,0.758127212,0.760495725,0.762376494,0.763717789,0.764586120,0.985689160,0.993160505,0.995931775,1.000000000),yr = c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,22,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,41,42,43,46))
```

I've tried parameter fitting by MLE through the nls function, but it throws an error

```
test <- nls(At$cumu ~ c * exp(-(At$yr/b)^a), start = list(a = .01, b = .2, c = 1))
```

The error:

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>     Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I presume the problem are wrong starting values. So my question is which starting values are suitable for my data?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Try `nls(cumu ~ c * exp(-(yr/b)^a), data = At, start = list(a = .01, b = .2, c = 1))`, but fails with your starting data.

Comment: thanks, I found a bunch of articles dealing with starting values, but for someone with my somewhat meagre stats background it is really hard to derive rules...it seems most people plot the data and then use their gut feeling for start values, which I can't do due to lack of experience. Any hints on how to get start values? Cheers!

Comment: I sampled random starting values until the MLE worked...turns out parameters are a = -0.5885, b = 32.2229  c = 2.0882. I did not expect this.

Comment: I gave a try to function `SSweibull`, but couldn't get it to run with your data. Maybe you could have a look.